# PHP/Sphinxsearch - searching for string or lat lng

Tags: php, search, sphinx

I need to find all results where city name matches string OR latitude and longitute is between given values. My index looks like this:

```
sql_field_string = city
sql_attr_float = lat
sql_attr_float = lng
```

Is there any way to use attributes in query? Or can I use in query values from $s->setSelect()? I know I can easily filter results using $s->setFilterFloatRange() but OR condition is essential for me in this case.

This works fine:

```
$s->SetFilterFloatRange('lat', $_GET['lat'] - $_GET['distance'], $_GET['lat'] + $_GET['distance']);
$s->SetFilterFloatRange('lng', $_GET['lng'] - $_GET['distance'], $_GET['lng'] + $_GET['distance']);
$s->Query('@city Amsterdam');
```

but it gives me rows where city is Amsterdam AND lat, lng between given values, but my problem is that I don't need filter (AND condition) I need OR.

I also know that I can use:

```
$s->setSelect('*, IF(lat<11,1,0) AS latitude');
```

but I belive i could use the 'latitude' only as a filter.

Comment: Please post what you've tried so far, some example input, the output you would expect, and the output you actually got.

Comment: Have already started replying to the version of this on sphinx forum http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=13136

Comment: @barryhunter Thank you, I was afraid to hear it's not possible. I ended up with performing 2 queries (addQuery API method) and getting one with higher count.