# Sphinx attribute in query

Tags: sphinx

Is there any way to search both string and float attribute with OR condition? I've tried this:

```
$s->SetServer('localhost', 3312);
$s->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2);
$s->SetArrayResult(false);
$s->SetLimits ( ($page-1)*$onsite, $onsite );
$s->SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_EXTENDED, '@id DESC');
$s->Query('@city "London" | floatrange=lat,51.0,51.2');
```

Comment: Is this the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27708773/php-sphinxsearch-searching-for-string-or-lat-lng - seems remarkably similar?